# Delphi XE5 right to left languages don't appear as they should in android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

as the title says , a text from a RTL language like persian or arabic doesnt show well in android 
for example the word "سلام" shows as "م ا ل س".
this problem happens even in text inputs (which i thought they were native and native android textboxes support that)
is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Bidi mode is not supported in FireMonkey. See [`QC 98644 All FireMonkey controls should have BiDiMode property`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98644).

Comment: wow the topic is from the year 2011 and still not fixed ..

Comment: I'd prefer that we have XPlatform rather than BiDi support, and add the latter at a future date. The majority of Delphi users don't work in RTL languages, AFAIK, based on traffic at the EMBT forums and here at SO. If a choice is "support the highest percentage of users first", it's usually the right one. :-) If bidi was done first, you wouldn't have Android support at all, and it wouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: I'd rather we had cross platform, and bidi, and a much less buggy product. I don't buy that these are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think absence of BiDi is the bigest blind spot of FM.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a firemonkey bug report.

Comment: Have you found any solution!?

Comment: No i haven't found a definitive solution yet.this topic is about a year and a half old , so there might be newer solutions to this matter , so please check the web.

Comment: See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per LURD's suggestions.
Download and use [D.P.F Delphi Android Native Components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/) and/or [D.P.F Delphi iOS Native Components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/).
That will fix the problem in XE7 and prior.
According to the documentation with the Delphi XE8 beta the problem is fixed there as well.

As a last resort (if you feel up to it), someone has taken the effort to patch the XE5 source code to enable BiDi support. See: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwumWe43CaijVDRQZzNQbXNSLWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 8):

Lack of Bidirectional and Glyph Shaping support is a [known restriction of the FireMonkey platform](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98644), on all targets (including Windows and Mac OSX).

We will have to wait for "native controls" for Android as third party components for FireMonkey, as it does exists for iOS - see http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsicl.asp for instance.

I've found [this great blog article with source code about Android Native controls for Lazarus/FreePascal](http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=simonsayz&logNo=120196870149&redirect=Dlog) which is quite interesting. But this won't work with the "NextGen" Delphi compiler, which is currently going in a diverse direction in respect to FPC (e.g. with the ObjectivePascal mode).

[image]

Since it uses *native Android controls*, it should not suffer from the same restrictions as FireMonkey do.

Comment: the last link your provided is really great , is there a way to actually use those Pascal Android native controls in delphi XE5?(i mean is there a way to add them as components in delphi and use them?)

Comment: @SNAKY it is in the source: "Free Pascal Compiler FPC 2.7.1, ( XE5 in near future )"

Comment: I just wrote a [small blog article about this... blog article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/09/19/FreePascal-Lazarus-and-Android-Native-Controls)... :) Only benefit is that it is in English. Could be good that those "Native UI components for FPC" projects are better known - in fact, there is a [sibling Native iOS Controls project using FPC available](http://blog.naver.com/simonsayz/120193098772) to target also iPhone/iPad devices

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is fmxrtl you can find at

> http://www.fmxrtl.com/