# FireMonkey Delphi XE 6 support for Arabic text

Tags: delphi, arabic, right-to-left

It seems FireMonkey doesn't support rendering of text in RTL languages such as Arabic.

I am using Delphi XE6 update 1, on Windows the text is displayed nicely, on Android the letters are rendered backwards while on the iOS the text is not rendered at all.

I there any way to resolve such issue?

Comment: This has been brought up many times already, Firemonkey doesn't support BiDi. You'll have to use platform native controls to get BiDi support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18883356

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi XE5 right to left languages don't appear as they should in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883356/delphi-xe5-right-to-left-languages-dont-appear-as-they-should-in-android)