# Delphi Xe8 right to left support

Tags: android, delphi, right-to-left, delphi-xe8, c++builder-xe8

I am writing an android application with Embarcadero Rad Sudio XE8 , "Delphi"

The application requires arabic text , when i create the button the button text is normal arabic ,  but when i deploy the app on the device as shown in the following figure , the text is inverted , hopefully can i find someone have a workaround for this issue :)

?[image]

Comment: [Bidi Right to Left Language in Firemonkey Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25666598/576719).

Comment: it doesn't support XE8

Comment: Are you targeting Android only? If so, it's a common mistake to use Delphi for just one single mobile platform. The main advantage of using Delphi / Firemonkey is cross-platform support. If all you need is Android, you should be using a native Android development tool.

Comment: No!! , i am using it for cross-platform developement

Comment: @JerryDodge It's either a good development tool or it isn't. If it isn't worth targeting one platform with, those drawbacks would just be multiplied if you targeted multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

FireMonkey currently has no support for right to left languages. Possible options for you include:

- Using native platform controls that do support right to left languages.
- Using native development tools that provide the support you need.

Comment: Not surprising - FMX still lacks tons of very basic features the more I use it.

Comment: :( is there any other work around ?

Comment: You want a quick fix but your fundamental problem is that you have chosen the wrong development tool.