# Right to Left Language in delphi xe7 Mobile android

Tags: android, delphi, arabic, right-to-left, farsi

I have an app in Delphi Xe7 for android mobile.
It works well For English Language .but bad for Farsi or Arabic Or The right-to-left languages .'سلام' ------> 'م ل ا س'
I found a few solutions

1. D.P.F Component for Xe7 and android .this bad for big app. in this component use base java  class to create component Like Java . i test this component and demo project Good Work . but if i add a Tabcontrol to my form and add a listview on the tabcontrol app not work and not show list view.
2. use FarsiReshaper.pas; this unit Right To left word and i use this Class to 
   convert string to show right to left.

   ```
   Procedure TForm1.Create(Sender:Tobject)
   var
     Farsi:TFarsi;
   Begin
     Button1.text:=Farsi.Convert(Button1.text)
   End
   ```

But this method is faulty

- For all component on form should run this code
- For listView and TreeView  component should run this Method for all Items and this Waste of time
- In edit mode like Tedit not work

Thanks 
Javad Adel

Comment: See [Bidi Right to Left Language in Firemonkey Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25666598/576719) and [Delphi XE5 right to left languages don't appear as they should in android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18883356/576719).

Comment: where to find FarsiReshaper ?

Answer (score 0):

FireMonkey does not yet support RTL languages. <strike>This is on the roadmap, I believe.</strike> It seems that is incorrect. So far as we can tell, supporting RTL is not even on Embarcadero's road map.

Until such a time as RTL support is added, it's hard to see Delphi as being a sensible option for you. The native Android development tools have comprehensive RTL support.

Comment: Not sure if there is a roadmap later than this one: [RAD Studio, Delphi and C++Builder Roadmap - April 2014](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677). No RTL language support listed there from what I can see.

Comment: Please help me to give ourselves the ability to write

Comment: @javad I cannot understand that comment